# Problems overloading the >> Operator

Tags: c++

I have the following block of code trying to overload the >> operator:

```
 istream &operator >> (istream &stream, const Currency &obj){
  cout << "Dollars: ";
  stream>>obj.dollars;
  cout<< "Cents: ";
  stream>> obj.cents;
  return stream;
 }
```

But when I call `cin>>newMoney` from my main program it keeps repeating "DOLLARS:" over and over again in an endless loop  like below:
[image]
Any ideas why?

Comment: Paste the complete code.

Comment: What type is obj.dollars and obj.cents? If 'Currency', then it should be obvious why you get the results you get.

Comment: It's also most unconventional to prompt for input in an `operator`.

Comment: @David Schwarts obj.dollars is an int and obj.cents is an int, declared as private.

Comment: And let me guess, you have a Currency constructor that takes an 'int', right?

Comment: @Johnsyweb I am just following the book example

Comment: @David Schwartz you are correct.  So I take it that is where the problem lies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no enough information in your code (as of now). Till you post more code, all I can say is this, which is also important for you to note down: since you overload `>>` to take input, the object `obj` should be passed by *non-const* reference, so remove `const` from the second parameter, and make it look like this:

```
istream &operator >> (istream &stream, Currency &obj)
```

Comment: The one `const` was all that was wrong with it, by removing the `const` from it, it works perfectly fine.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I bet you have a Currency constructor that takes an 'int'. So `stream>>obj.dollars;` is the same as `stream>>Currency(obj.dollars);`. The function you pasted outputs "Dollars: " and then calls itself, outputting "Dollars: " again and then repeating forever.

I'd suggest making the constructor [explicit](http://www.glenmccl.com/tip_023.htm) so it doesn't misfire on you.

Comment: Why `So stream>>obj.dollars; is the same as stream>>Currency(obj.dollars);`? Could you explain this please?

Comment: You have a 'Currency' constructor that takes an 'int'. Since it's not explicit, an 'int' can be converted into a 'Currency'. Unless a constructor is safe in all cases, it should be made 'explicit' so it isn't used as a conversion in placed where that's not what you want.

Comment: That makes sense only if you write like this : `Currency c = obj.dollars`. But `stream >> obj.dollars` is a different case. Your comment doesn't explain this. For example, replace `stream >> obj.dollars` with `int i; stream >> i` inside the function, then are you saying the behaviour would be same?

Comment: @Nawaz: the problem occurs because `obj` is (incorrectly) declared as a reference to const. There is no overload for `operator>>(istream&, int const&)`, but `operator>>(istream&, Currency const&)` is compatible due to the non-explicit constructor, so that's chosen instead.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That doesn't seem to be a correct explanation, because that means if I replace the older code with this : `const int i = 0; stream >> i`, then the behaviour would be same as `stream >> obj.dollars`, but that doesn't seem to be the case. It gives error, instead.

Comment: @Nawaz: it seems to allow a zero-valued integer constant to be treated as a null pointer constant, giving more potential overloads. Try `const int i = 1;` instead. (Off the top of my head, I'm not sure whether that's a compiler bug, or a strange corner case in the definition of null pointer constants).